# UK Standard visitor visa for Tourism

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Recently i travelled to UK on business trip and hold a UK standard visitor Visa valid for six months.

Now i want to travel to Scotland and Ireland for tourism. I cannot see anywhere on my visa that its only for business. It only says "C-Visit".

Can i use the same visa for Tourism?

Comment: Yes, those visa are good for multiple visits and you can engage in any activity listed in Appendix 3 of Appendix V of the rules, no problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your visa gives you the privilege of visiting throughout the UK (England, Wales, Scotland, Northern Ireland) wheher it be on business, visiting friends, or tourism.

[**APPENDIX V: Immigration Rules for visitors**](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

> A visitor is a person who is coming to the UK, usually for up to six months, for a temporary purpose, for example as a tourist, to visit friends or family or to carry out a business activity.

Appendix 3 details 24 permitted activities for all visa holders (except transit visitors) beginning with Tourist and Leisure, Volunteering, and Business, and so forth.